# JMS java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)

Tags: java, apache-spark, jms

New to JMS 
Requirement - connect to Message queue . try to send some file/message to test the connection.

Getting [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBx0A.png)-  ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://dbusmq-sd00007.svc.db.com:1427 due to: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)
java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://dbusmq-sd00007.svc.db.com:1427 due to: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)

its firewall/SSL issue or something wrong with code ?

package practice;

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;

public class jmsQueue {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, Exception {
        BrokerService broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker(new URI(
                "broker:(tcp://dbusmq-sd00007.svc.db.com:1427)"));
        broker.start();
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            // Producer
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                    "tcp://dbusmq-sd00007.svc.db.com:1427");
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue queue = session.createQueue("QM.SU00007");
            String payload = "Testing helloworld";
            Message msg = session.createTextMessage(payload);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            System.out.println("Sending text '" + payload + "'");
            producer.send(msg);

            // Consumer
/*            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
            connection.start();
            TextMessage textMsg = (TextMessage) consumer.receive();
            System.out.println(textMsg);
            System.out.println("Received: " + textMsg.getText());*/
            session.close();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
            broker.stop();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not a local IP address of the local machine. You can't bind to someone else's IP address.

Comment: then how I can send message/file to Message queue ?